# Real Analysis by H. L. Royden, Is the argument really in harmony with definition proposed by the author?

Tags: measure-theory

In the text “Real Analysis by H. L. Royden, 2010” the author defined the outer measure in 2.2 as:[image]

However for the case of bounded closed interval in the proof of the proposition 1 (section 2.2) that length of an interval is its outer measure, he had done the following:

[image]

where in considering the cover $(I_n)_n$ for $[a,b]$  he took $I_1=(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon),$ and $I_k=\emptyset~\forall~k\ge2.$ However taking empty interval as an element of the cover is not permissible due to the definition.

Even though in the definition of countability the author considered finiteness earlier, the symbol $\infty$ in $\{I_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ provokes me to think the countable collection as countabily infinite (the elements are non necessarily distinct).

Is the argument really in harmony with definition proposed by the author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do agree the definition it's a little ambiguous. If the author specifies you're working with sequences then we necessarily need to put an empty set after some point. If the author uses collections of sets, then one needs to be clear about repetitions. Using the sequence definition seems cleaner when defining the sum of the lengths of the interval, and thus a good option would be to drop the requierment that intervals cannot be empty, hence "terminating" sequences can appear, and thus finite covers, and finite sums, as you want to.

Comment: I agree it is best to use "countable cover" including the possibility of finite cover.  As stated, with countably infinite covers, we could always add on countably many extra intervals, whose lengths sum to something as small as we like.

Comment: @GEdgar True, yet that seems unnecessary vs. putting an empty interval and being done with it.

Comment: Lots of these variations will work fine for Lebesgue measure in the real line, but not in the abstract Caratheodory context.  I know from experience that when you write a textbook including this, you have to be careful of these things.

Comment: @GEdgar Sure. I am no expert at all, so be free to give an answer that might be more helpful than my attempt to comfort the OP. =)